How can I ensure that locate will search into my user home folder? (macOS)
The locate command doesn't list any search results from files that are in my home folder. Is there a config file to tweak to enable this behavior?
sudo locate word didn't work, nor did updating the locate database.
MacBook Pro, Sequoia, bash 3.2.57. Thanks!

Is your home folder publicly readable? ls -ld ~ and check if it starts with drwxr-xr-x (publicly readable) or drwx------ (only readable by you). It takes extra work to make locate find files in private directories and I don't know if the macOS version does this extra work.

I ran chmod 755 ~ ending up with drwxr-xr-x but it still doesn't list files downstream of ~! 777 didn't do it either...

Am I supposed to do something with the LOCATE_PATH variable? Which is currently empty. This time, restarting the shell hasn't magically fixed anything...

I also ran sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb with no luck...

You should probably look for answers on the sister site that is for MacOS.
